# Foundation flex box stretch alignment with text vertically centered

Tags: zurb-foundation

I was doing the tutorial here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-to-know-the-flexbox-grid-in-foundation-6 and was trying the stretch here:

https://codepen.io/chrisoncode/pen/wMWEVE

```
    <p class="text-center">Aligned Stretch (Columns are Equal Height)</p>
<div class="row align-stretch text-center">
    <div class="columns">space</div>
    <div class="columns">
      <p>Look I'm a bunch of words. Spoiler alert for Star Wars: Jar Jar Binks is the new sith lord. He is Darth Darth Binks.</p>
    </div>
</div>

body          { padding-top:50px; }
.row          { border:1px solid #FF556C; margin-bottom:20px; }
.columns      { background:#048CB9; color:#FFF; padding:20px; }
.columns:first-child { background:#085A78;vertical-align:bottom }
.columns:last-child  { background:#B3BBBB; }
```

On the 3rd example, using the stretch property, I am trying to get the text to vertically align middle and am having no luck.  Can anyone tell me how to do it?

I tried adding .columns:first-child { background:#085A78;vertical-align:bottom } but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<p class="text-center">Aligned Stretch (Columns are Equal Height)</p>
<div class="row align-stretch text-center">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="row align-center text-center"><p>space</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <p>Look I'm a bunch of words. Spoiler alert for Star Wars: Jar Jar Binks is the new sith lord. He is Darth Darth Binks.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.row.align-stretch.text-center .columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.row.align-stretch.text-center .columns p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex children are equal height by default, unless you assign an align-items value other than stretch.

Therefor:

```
<div class="row align-stretch text-center">
```

Is the same as:

```
<div class="row text-center">
```

For your example, the simplest way is to use the `.align-middle` which will make the column the height of the content within and vertically center it to the taller column in the group.

[image: Example from your codepen]

Otherwise, you can make the column itself `display: flex;` and add `align-items: center;`

Comment: Your solution centers the div, but does not stretch it.  I wanted to use the stretch and also vertically align the text inside.